$R$ is a domain but not a GCD domain, does $r \in \text{Frac}(R)$ has an (not necessarily unique) expression in lowest terms?
The complete question is:

Let $R$ be a integral domain but not a GCD domain. Prove or disprove:
$\forall r \in \text{Frac}(R), \exists a,b \in R$ s.t. $r= a/b$ and if
$c \mid a,b$, then $c$ is a unit.

I know that if $R$ is a UFD, then we can find the unique expression by cancelling the gcd$(a,b)$. I am wondering could we generalize this conclusion to any integral domain removing the requirement of uniqueness.
Consider $4, 2+2\sqrt{-3} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, $\displaystyle \frac{2(1+\sqrt{-3})}{4} = \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} = \frac{2}{1-\sqrt{-3}}$. Since $2,1+\sqrt{-3},1-\sqrt{-3}$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, then both $\displaystyle \frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{2}{1-\sqrt{-3}}$ is the answer in this case.

I think maybe if $R$ is noetherian it would be true: if you take a sequence of expressions $a_n / b_n$ by subsequently factoring out non-units, then the increasing sequence of ideals $\langle a_1 \rangle, \langle a_2 \rangle, \ldots$ must stabilize at some point...  Haven't checked the details though.

Hint: $ $ No, e.g. in $,\Bbb Q[x,y,z]\left[\left{\dfrac{x}{z^n},\dfrac{y}{z^n}\right}{{\large n> 0}}\right],$ show $,{\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{f}{g}},\Rightarrow, z\mid f,g\ \ $

@Bill Dubuque Thank you for the example. Could we simplify this example to $(\mathbb{Q}[z])\left[ { \frac{x}{z^n},\frac{y}{z^n} \mid n>0 } \right]$? Besides, if we add the condition that R is noetherian, would the conclusion be correct?
